# Way of proving that f is a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

My question:
Let $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ open.

Is it true that if $\forall z \in G$ $f$ is holomorphic in a ball $B(z,r_z)$ with center $z$, then $f$ is holomorphic in $G$?

According to my understanding of a holomorphic function this should be true, but since I'm fairly new to complex analysis I'm not entirely sure.

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: My definition of a holomorphic function is:

$f$ is holomorphic in $G$ if $f$ is complex differentiable $\forall z \in G$

Comment: What is your definition of “holomorphic function”?

Comment: @MartinR Sorry forgot to mention that. I edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: The statement is true. What exactly is your doubt about the conclusion?

Comment: Thanks! I kind of doubted it because it would give me a way to use theorems that require star domains even if $G$ is not a star domain, but I think my doubts were not justified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z_0 \in G$, then there is $r_{z_0} >0$ such that $f$ is holomorphic in $B(z_0,r_{z_0})$. Hence $f$ is complex differentiable in $z_0$.

Since $z_0 \in G$ was arbitrary, $f$ is holomorphic in $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a small follow-up question: So it is possible to use Moreras theorem on all balls $B(z,r_z)$ when proving that f is holomorphic in $G$?